# PyQT5: How to pass QLineEdit string from one class to another?

Tags: python, pyqt5, invoice, qlineedit

I am writing an application which generates invoices. 
I have two windows. In the first one I am gathering data from a user (name, address etc.) by using QLineEdit. Then I want to pass this data to another class to make an invoice. How can I do it?

```
class FormularzFaktury(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormularzFaktury, self).__init__(parent)

(...)
        nazwiskonabywcyLbl = QLabel('Imię i nazwisko/nazwa: ')
        self.nazwiskonabywcy = QLineEdit(self)
        uklad.addWidget(nazwiskonabywcyLbl, 2, 0)

(...)

    def dodajprodukty(self):
        self.DP = DodajProdukty()
        self.DP.show()

class DodajProdukty(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DodajProdukty, self).__init__(parent)

(...)
    def show_nazwiskonabywcy(self)
        nazwiskonabywcy=self.nazwiskonabywcy.text()
        print(nazwiskonabywcy)
```

How to pass self.nazwiskonabywcy.text() from the first class to the second class?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante I've already edited

Comment: How do you create those dialogs? Are they shown concurrently? Is there a "main" program or something that shows those dialogs? And how? Please carefully read that link: the example code should not only be minimal, but also *reproducible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `self.nazwiskonabywcy` as a parameter to `DodajProdukty` and then set it to its own `self.nazwiskonabywcy`, so the code would look like this:

```
class FormularzFaktury(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormularzFaktury, self).__init__(parent)

        nazwiskonabywcyLbl = QLabel('Imię i nazwisko/nazwa: ')
        self.nazwiskonabywcy = QLineEdit(self)
        uklad.addWidget(nazwiskonabywcyLbl, 2, 0)

    def dodajprodukty(self):
        self.DP = DodajProdukty(self.nazwiskonabywcy)
        self.DP.show()

class DodajProdukty(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, nazwiskonabywcy, parent=None):
        super(DodajProdukty, self).__init__(parent)
        self.nazwiskonabywcy = nazwiskonabywcy

    def show_nazwiskonabywcy(self)
        nazwiskonabywcy=self.nazwiskonabywcy.text()
        print(nazwiskonabywcy)
```

Or if `self.nazwiskonabywcy` is already set to the correct text at the point where `DodajProdukty` is instantiated, you can just pass the value directly to the new class, instead of passing the whole `QLineEdit`:

```
class FormularzFaktury(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormularzFaktury, self).__init__(parent)

        nazwiskonabywcyLbl = QLabel('Imię i nazwisko/nazwa: ')
        self.nazwiskonabywcy = QLineEdit(self)
        uklad.addWidget(nazwiskonabywcyLbl, 2, 0)

    def dodajprodukty(self):
        self.DP = DodajProdukty(self.nazwiskonabywcy.text())
        self.DP.show()

class DodajProdukty(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, nazwiskonabywcy, parent=None):
        super(DodajProdukty, self).__init__(parent)
        self.nazwiskonabywcy = nazwiskonabywcy

    def show_nazwiskonabywcy(self)
        print(self.nazwiskonabywcy)
```